# How to install Scrapy in multi-Python Mac environment?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to install Scrapy on my Mac. I am a complete Python newcomer. I know Mac OS X comes pre-installed with a version of Python. However, best practice (I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhutbLBKBok)), including [Scrapy's own advice](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html), appears to recommend installing a "proper" version that does not conflict.

- I used "`brew install python`". This installed Python 2.7.12.
- I also used "`brew install python3`". This installed Python 3.5.2.
- OS X appeared to ship with 2.7.6.

I added "`export PATH=/usr/local/share/python3:$PATH`" to the path, to ensure shells start with Python 3.
Current path is "`/usr/local/share/python3:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`"
I believe the second path is the 2.X one I installed myself.

Now that it comes to installing Scrapy, I am confused. Scrapy [install documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html) says to use "`pip install Scrapy`". However, I'm not sure whether this will run pip for the pre-installed Python, my new 2.X Python or my new 3.X Python.

Should I run "`pip install Scrapy`" or "`pip3 install Scrapy`"? My instinct says the former.

Comment: Advice! pick a flavor and stick with for a while, otherwise you will doing alot of installing versions and maintenance.. I am a fan of 2.x ... pips3 will install p3 version of scrapy